# Why is my Serializable UID not used?

Tags: android, serialization, deserialization

My class looks like following:

```
public class LoadedPhoneContact implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6706261139182218494L;
    // ...
}
```

And I retreived following error from a user:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: ....LoadedPhoneContact; 
    local class incompatible: 
    stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 6683493845353264429, 
    local class serialVersionUID = 1206205895855870477
```

How can this happen? Non of the ids in the exception match the current defined id, even if the import file would be years old and would be made with a old version where I did not define the id manually, the local class id in the log should be the current one, shouldn't it?

Any ideas why my id is not used/working?

Comment: You haven't deployed the correct version of the .class file to the local classpath.

Comment: It seems to be a proguard (obfuscation) issue... Have found something in this direction, that makes sense and seems to be the reason, will have to test it though...